# How do I split/parse this String properly using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am inexperienced with regex and rusty with JAVA, so some help here would be appreciated.

So I have a String in the form:

```
statement|digit|statement

statement|digit|statement
```

etc.

where statement can be any combination of characters, digits, and spaces.
I want to parse this string such that I save the first and last statements of each line in a separate string array.

for example if I had a string:

```
cats|1|short hair and long hair

cats|2|black, blue

dogs|1|cats are better than dogs
```

I want to be able to parse the string into two arrays.

```
Array one = [cats], [cats], [dogs]

Array two = [short hair and long hair],[black, blue],[cats are better than dogs]

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\.+)|\\d+|=(\\.+)").matcher(str);

        while(m.find()) {
          String key = m.group(1);
          String value = m.group(2);
          System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", key, value);
        }
```

I would have continued to add the keys and values into seperate arrays had my output been right but no luck. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just split using `|` and access individual array elements using `arr[0]` and `arr[2]`

Comment: JAVA, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with RegEx:

```
public class ParseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "cats|1|short hair and long hair\n"+
                      "cats|2|black, blue\n"+
                      "dogs|1|cats are better than dogs";
        List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> result2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\|\\d+\\|(.+)");

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);
        while (m.find()) {
           String key = m.group(1);
           String value = m.group(2);
           result1.add(key);
           result2.add(value);
           System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a great site to help with regex http://txt2re.com/ expressions.  Enter some example text in step one. Select the parts you are interested in part 2. And select a language in step 3.  Then copy, paste and massage the code that it spits out.

Comment: Hey good answer, I am going to update it because his input is a multiline string. Your answer will work for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Double split should work:

```
class ParseString
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
    String s = "cats|1|short hair and long hair\ncats|2|black, blue\ndogs|1|cats are better than dogs";
    String[] sa1 = s.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sa1.length; i++)
    {  
      String[] sa2 = sa1[i].split("\\|");
      System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", sa2[0], sa2[2]);
    } // end for i
  } // end main
} // end class ParseString
```

Output:

```
key=cats, value=short hair and long hair
key=cats, value=black, blue
key=dogs, value=cats are better than dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to escape `|` and not the `.`. Also what is the `=` doing in your regex? I generalized the regex a little bit but you can replace `.*` by `\\d+` to have the same as you.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\|.*\\|(.+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(str);
```

Here is the *strict* version:`"^([^|]+)\\|\\d+\\|([^|]+)$"` (also with MULTILINE)

And it's indeed easier using `split` (on the lines) as some have said, but like this:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\|\\d+\\|");
```

If `parts.length` is not two then you know it is not a legal line.

If your input is always formatted like that, then you can just do with this **single statement** to get the *left part in the even indexes* and the *right part in the odd indexes* (0: *line1-left*, 1: *line1-right*, 2: *line2-left*, 3: *line2-right*, 4: *line3-left* ...), so you will get an array twice the size of line count.

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\|\\d+\\||\\n+");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that you should use split, but I am providing an answer that uses Pattern.split, since it uses a regex.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class MatchExample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[] data = {
            "cats|1|short hair and long hair",
            "cats|2|black, blue",
            "dogs|1|cats are better than dogs"
        };
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|\\d+\\|");
        for(String line: data){

            String[] elements = p.split(line);
            System.out.println(elements[0] + " // " + elements[1]);

        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the pattern will match on one or more digits between two |'s. I see what you are doing with the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a complex regex pattern, you could simple **split** the string by the demiliter **token** using the string's split method ([String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))) on Java.

### Working Example

```
public class StackOverFlow31840211 {
    private static final int SENTENCE1_TOKEN_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int DIGIT_TOKEN_INDEX = SENTENCE1_TOKEN_INDEX + 1;
    private static final int SENTENCE2_TOKEN_INDEX = DIGIT_TOKEN_INDEX + 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] text = {
            "cats|1|short hair and long hair",
            "cats|2|black, blue",
            "dogs|1|cats are better than dogs"
        };

        ArrayList<String> arrayOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String s : text) {
            String[] tokens = s.split("\\|");

            int tokenType = 0;
            for (String token : tokens) {
                switch (tokenType) {
                    case SENTENCE1_TOKEN_INDEX:
                        arrayOne.add(token);
                        break;

                    case SENTENCE2_TOKEN_INDEX:
                        arrayTwo.add(token);
                        break;
                }

                ++tokenType;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sentences for first token: " + arrayOne);
        System.out.println("Sentences for third token: " + arrayTwo);

    }
}
```